# Is the expression 「だってある」 common?

Tags: usage, nuances, colloquial-language

I just stumbled upon this sentence in a book.

> とはいうものの、電気やエルクトロニクスの基本を知る価値**だってある**。

I can get the gist of what the sentence is trying to say, but this is the first time I encountered the expression written in bold. Is it common? Can you explain to me in what kind of situation do we typically use this expression?

Comment: Do you know how to use だって?

Comment: Pardon me, but does「だって」 has the same nuance like "but... but..."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the relevant dictionary definition is sense 一・① in 大辞林

> **だって**
> 〔断定の助動詞「だ」に助詞「とて」の付いた「だとて」の転。近世江戸語以降の語。くだけた話し言葉に用いる〕
>
> **一** （係助）
> 体言またはそれに助詞の付いたもの，副詞などに接続する。特にある事物をとりあげて示す。「も」にくらべて語調が強い。
>
> ① ある特別と思われる場合をあげて，それも他と同様であるということを表す。「…もやはり…だ」「…であっても…だ」の意を表す。…でも。 「さる－木から落ちるさ」 「ぼくに－チャンスはある」 「今すぐ－いいよ」
>
> ② [...]
>
> **二** （終助）
>
> [...]

だって effectively could be replaced with も, but だって makes for a stronger contrast. You haven't given any context, but the speaker is obviously contrasting something that was said before (とはいうものの). So, without knowing any more context, I would translate it as

> とはいうものの、電気やエルクトロニクスの基本を知る価値**だって**ある。
> Be that as it may, knowing the basics about electricity or electronics is **still** worth it.